# Command Line Mass Rename Jpg Files

Tags: command-line

I have a folder full of jpg files which all end with "-x-large.jpg" I would like to rename them all using command line so that it gets rid of the -x-large and just becomes .jpg.

So for example 123-x-large.jpg will become 123.jpg

Can someone tell me how I can do this with the ren command?

Thanks.

Comment: What command line are you asking for?  There is now one CMD (Windows) answer and one Posix/GNU (Mac and/or Linux) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for img in *-x-large.jpg; do mv -i -v "$img" "${img%-x-large.jpg}.jpg"; done
```

This loops on all matching images and moves them into a new file with a truncated name (removing `-x-large.jpg` from the end) with the `.jpg` added back to the end of the file name.  I'm invoking this interactively with `mv -i` so you are prompted before overwriting each file.  To force overwriting (always say "yes"), change that to `mv` (remove the `-i`).  To prevent overwriting (always say "no"), change that to `mv -n`.

Remove the `-v` (verbose) if you don't want to see each rename happen.

If you have a very large number of these files, the command line will be too long for the above command (since `*-x-large.jpg` will be expanded onto a command line).  You can work around that with `find` and `xargs` as follows:

```sh
sh <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*-x-large.jpg' \
  |sed -r 's/(.*)(-x-large.jpg)$/mv -i "\1\2" "\1.jpg"/')
```

This creates a shell script using bash [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), using `find` to generate a list of all files we want to rename and then piping them through `sed` to create the `mv` commands.
(See above for the `mv` flags.  I removed `-v` because presumably this will be a very long list.)
See the version below if you want to check the script before running it.

The above one-liner requires GNU bash or Korn shell (ksh) as well as GNU sed.
Here's how to do it with neither (in three commands):

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*-x-large.jpg' \
  |sed 's/.*/mv "&" "&/; s/-x-large.jpg$/.jpg"/' > temp.sh
sh temp.sh
rm temp.sh
```

[Posix sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't reliably support capture groups (`\(…\)` or `sed -r` to invoke [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04)) and therefore we can't expect it to be able to match and recall text, so this version simply writes most of the command and then fixes the ending (the absence of a trailing double quotes in the first replacement is intentional; we add it in the second replacement).  [Posix shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) (`/bin/sh` proper) doesn't support process substitution, so we dump to a temporary file, evaluate it, and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If we're referring to Windows command-line, then `SET /?` is your friend. Loads of good info in there.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set SEARCH_SUFFIX=-x-large.jpg
set REPLACE_SUFFIX=.jpg
for %%A in ("*%SEARCH_SUFFIX%") do (
    set OLD_NAME=%%~nxA
    set NEW_NAME=!OLD_NAME:%SEARCH_SUFFIX%=%REPLACE_SUFFIX%!
    ren "!OLD_NAME!" "!NEW_NAME!"
)
endlocal
```